# what is " Override resource in other configuration " error in Android studio.

Tags: android, android-studio

It happens when I gave the scale type to an image and the image doesn't get changed when i change the scale type.
If I click on the error it takes me to " Select resource directory"
where it asks me for a directory name and resource type.
What should i do to debug the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is an recommendation by android studio to provide alternative resources. Let's consider a case where you are using some properties which are supported only after certain API level. For ex. i am using `android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"`   property with TextView which is supported from API 23 so it would give me suggestion "Override resouce in layout-v23".This is just an example to make you understand the meaning of that error so there maybe other cases where this error might be generated. You can visit following site for more info on Providing alternative resources:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources